# Can I use bookmarks/custom activity in Workflow designer?

Tags: c#, workflow, android-activity, workflow-foundation-4, bookmarks

This is sort of a noob question...

I've seen how to create an activity that works with bookmarks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489442.aspx), but how can I use this custom code as an Activity inside a workflow designer?

Comment: do you mean in Visual Studio's workflow designer on in a rehosted workflow designer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio any activity in the same solution will automatically be added to the toolbox when you open the workflow designer. If you are using self hosting or a previously created library of activities in VS2010 you need to add it to the toolbox yourselfs.

Comment: ok, that's weird - I was using another project, referenced it, but only graphically designed activities were in the toolbox. Now I see both... anyhow, thanks

Comment: Did you rebuild? VS2010 uses reflection so activities don't show up until you rebuild the solution.